# PostgreSQL - Generate CREATE scripts for database schema: Procedures, Triggers, Sequences

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to generate Create scripts from database objects separately per schema for e.g. separate file for sequence, triggers, tables, procedures, indexes.

But seems that we can only create separate file per tables only with `pd_dump` -t option.

Is there no option to extract sequence, triggers, procedures, indexes separately? I tried  `--section post-data` but it only exported constraints.

```
pg_dump -d edb_db -U enterprisedb -t schema.customertbl --section post-data >> samplefile.sql;
```

Also can i generate a script per procedure in a schema?

Like below

```
  pg_dump -d edb_db -U enterprisedb -n schema.proc_batch > samplefile.sql;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need it, but you can dump the whole database without the data by using `--schema-only`, and then it's a pretty trivial script to separate the `CREATE TABLE` commands into a separate file.

Comment: @TimRoberts i need CREATE SEQUENCE in separate file and then CREATE PROCEDURE in separate files